# Are maximum order and maximum disorder equally easy to describe?

Tags: entropy, information, disorder

If we have a collection of particles in a maximum ordered state, is this state just as easy to describe as a collection of particles in a minimum ordered state?

If we have a collection of particles say in gaseous form than it seems to me that if you know how one part of the gas looks like, you know how the whole gas looks like.

The same can be said for particles in a well-ordered crystal at low temperature.

So are they just as easy to describe (apart from the precise positions of the particles)? And will systems which lay between these two extremes be the most difficult to describe?

So a box of gas at a certain temperature and pressure is not very different from other boxes with the same content. The same can be said of many equal crystals at low temperature. But the difference between two (non-similar) macromolecules is rather big.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only if your perspective is coarse-grained in some fashion. A full description of the gas you mention, for example, classically must include the position and momentum of every gas particle, while the description of the crystal can be significantly compressed. For example, with a $\operatorname{Na}\operatorname{Cl}$ salt crystal, you just need to specify the orientation of the lattice(s), describe the edges, and any defects/impurities in the crystal. That's many fewer degrees of freedom for the same number of atoms.

Put another way, the "disordered" states are those that have many possible states associated with their coarse grained description, while the ordered ones have many fewer states that are consistent with the coarse grained picture.

Comment: I agree. But aren't both extremes equally easy to describe, without looking at the individual constituents?